# scp command doesn't transfer files

Tags: server, ssh, scp

I'm trying to upload a folder to the root directory at my server

```
$ scp -r folder root@my.server.ip:
```

then I see some like: [image: terminal]

However when I go to server

```
ssh root@my.server.ip
```

and check files (using `ls`) there's no new files. How to upload correctly?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Instead, copy/[paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: Also, you're not uploading to the root directory. Are your files in `/root`?

Comment: Have you tried using the command more specific? `scp -r localhost:/path/to/your/folder root@my.server.ip:/root`

Comment: @terdon @ADDB with `:/root` in the end and full path to the folder: it still not appear at server

Comment: @IlyaBlokh please answer my question. Are your files in `/root` on the remote server? Not in the "root directory" (`/`) but in `/root`, the home directory of the user `root`. Your scp command didn't give a target path so by default, it will copy the files to the home directory of the user. So, please check the directory `/root`.

Comment: @terdon done with it. I used full path to directory without 'localhost' prefix. Uploaded

Comment: @IlyaBlokh I don't understand why you keep ignoring my questions. But fine, if you solved it, please post an answer. I can't since you haven't given me the information I asked for so I can't give a useful answer that would help future users.

Comment: @terdon I don't even have `/root ` directory at server

Comment: Then where did you copy your files to? Your answer says you copied to `/root`.

Comment: it seems I missed something. however this command works and I can't see /root directory at server from admin user.

Answer (score 1):

That worked for me:

```
$ scp -r full/path/to/the/folder root@my.server.ip:/root
```

excerpt from man page:

```
Note that scp follows symbolic links encountered in
             the tree traversal.
```